# How to change input textfiled [Swift]

Tags: swift, uitextfield

In my swift app I've two textfields and as inputView is UIDatePicker().
Here's my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField2: UITextField!

    var timePicker = UIDatePicker()

    var timeString = String()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        timePicker.datePickerMode = .time
    }

    @objc func formatData(_ datePickerView: UIDatePicker) {
        let timeFormatter = DateFormatter()
        timeFormatter.timeStyle = .short
        timeString = timeFormatter.string(from: datePickerView.date)
    }

    @IBAction func textFieldChanged(_ sender: UITextField) {
        sender.inputView = timePicker
        timePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(formatData(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        sender.text = timeString
    }
 }
```

By this way to change value into text field I've to deselect it and then rettapping on it the value appear.
But it's not correct.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Can you give an example of what you need? Or explain what is happening now?

Answer (score -1):

first you take the IBAction of that textfield which you want to change the input view and name should be of your IBAction method  didBeginEditing and in that method you can the input view of that textfield which you want to change